# How to get some string from JsonObject?

Tags: android, json, gson

I got from server response by retrofit, that is actually JsonObject(using Gson):

```
{"a": "a and its content 1", "b": [{"b_1": "string: b_1", "b_2": 2222}]}
```

so that I get it like this:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = response.body();
```

And then I can log it:

```
Log.d(TAG, jsonObject.get("a")+"");
```

// log: "a and its content 1"

**question:**

How can I log only "string: b_1"? (from `"b_1": "string: b_1"`)

As it is in array [], hard to get it for me.

Comment: b is an array you have to parse array to get string out of it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one work for me,

```
 try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = response.body();
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("b");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String b_1 = jsonObj.getString("b_1");
                int b_2 = jsonObj.getInt("b_2");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
try{

JsonObject jsonObject = response.body();
JSONArray a = jsonObject.getJSONArray("b")
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
Log.d("Type", a.getString(i));
}

}catch(Exception e){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like below

```
JSONObject jObj = response.body();
JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("b");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
  Log.d(TAG, jsonObject.getString("b_1")+"");
  Log.d(TAG, jsonObject.getInt("b_2")+"");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
 String status = String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("a"));
```